# ListPopupWindow marign bottom not working

Tags: android, popup, margins

I'm trying to show a ListPopupWindow on clicking listview item. The items in the ListPopupWindow is scrollable. But i'm not able to give bottom margin to it and it touches the bottom of screen.

```
private ListPopupWindow getListMenu(Context context, View anchor, String[] options) {
    Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ProfilePicPopUp);
    ListPopupWindow popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(wrapper);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.listpopup_item, options);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    popupWindow.setAdapter(adapter);
    popupWindow.setAnchorView(anchor);
    popupWindow.getAnimationStyle();
    popupWindow.setModal(true);
    popupWindow.setHorizontalOffset( (anchor.getWidth()*3)/4);
    popupWindow.setVerticalOffset(-anchor.getHeight()/4);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    popupWindow.setWidth((width * 3) / 4); // note: don't use pixels, use a dimen resource


    return popupWindow;
}
```

listpopup_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    fontPath="Lato-Bold.ttf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/profilepic_option_click_selector"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dip"
    android:paddingStart="14dip"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:text="sample"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Could you post your `xml` layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browse codes in ListPopupWindow, I contain a listview, so you can try this codes to set margin bottom for listview.

```
   ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) listPopupWindow.getListView()
            .getLayoutParams();

    mlp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, yourMarginBottom);
```

If you want a flexible `ListView`, you can create a custom view of `PopupWindow`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Look at the padding element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="10dip"        
   android:background="@color/colorbg">    
</LinearLayout>
```